# How to include JavaScript based plugin in MVC 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 with Visual Studio 2010, and though VS 2010 has functionality like "Add Existing Item", I see only two folders, Content, Scripts. And when I use "Add Existing Item" it copies only js and css files in these folders. Yes I can create new folder and move them there but, it seems MVC 4 has its own settings for maintaining scripts and styles.

I want to add plugins like TinyMCE editor, fMath editor, jsTree, jQuery, jQuery UI etc... which contain javascript files but also need css styles, png spritesheets, fonts etc... to work.

What is the proper way to include these plugins in my project?

Should I put all styles/fonts/spritesheets in the Content folder and min.js files in Scripts folder or should I create separate folder for plugins only and keep both the styles and script in their own plugin folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Content should be used to develop and keep your own CSS files. The same applies to your scripts, they should be kept in Scripts folder. As for  the external plugins which contain both CSS and JavaScript files but also other resources, I think a separate Plugin folder should be used and put all plugins there.

You can use drag and drop to add complete folders of files to Visual Studio 2010.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: visual studio 2010 external plugins]

I keep TinyMCE, jQuery, jQuery UI, FMath and jsTree in the Plugins folder.